# How can I get the two chests in the Resistance camp?

Tags: nier-automata

I see that there are two chests to get in the Resistance Camp, but I can't figure out how to find them. I've already completed the two Sorting quests.  You can see the two oddly shaped blue shapes in the upper right of the picture.

[image: Chest location]

Comment: I'm almost positive that the two chests you're seeing on the map are within the area that the Sorting quests are given to you... I never had that HUD chip on, so I don't remember those chests per se, but I'm pretty sure that's the only place there. Have you done the third sorting quest? Maybe they are chests that appear after completing it?

Comment: @Vemonus I've done all the sorting quests (including the one outside the camp itself).  Do the chests appear in the puzzle area, because I've never been able to get back into the puzzle room unless the quest was active.  And with all of the complete, the guy that gives you the quest is gone and there's an invisible wall blocking the door.

Comment: important question, did you open all of the bonus chests during the Sorting quests? I think that might be what they are. They aren't available once those quests have been completed, either.

Comment: @Vemonus I thought I did, but I can't be sure, it was a while ago.

Comment: my file hasn't done hardly any side quests yet, so I'll see if I can find that HUD chip and whether those chests are the ones I'm thinking they are.

Comment: @Vemonus Much appreciated.

Comment: Do you happen to know where you got the HUD chip that shows where chests are?

Comment: @Vemonus I believe I purchased it from the Desert supply trader near the end of the route B path.  I did find an answer to my question though.

Comment: @Vemonus I have seen some posts that suggest you can buy it early in route B in the camp itself or in the machine village, shortly after completing the desert main quest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I played through again starting from scratch.  The chip that shows chests (and harvest points) on the map can be had near the end of the B route play through.  Immediately after I acquired it, I could see only one chest on the map.  I had completed Sorting Troubles 1 already.  One chest remained marked until Sorting Troubles 2 became available near the beginning of the C route play through, and then two chests appeared.

I completed that quests, and the chests were removed from the minimap.  Leaving the camp though resets them so they show again, but because the quest is complete you cannot access that area again.  The chests don't contain items; they are key items required to complete the two Sorting Trouble quests and seem to return when leaving the area.